# padding leading zeros (0 characters) in some string

Tags: c

I have to fill a **string** (containing numerals) with leading zeros if the content of that string was less than string's *size*.

example:

```
char str[11] = "12345";
```

The expected output should be: **0000012345**

I have padded `string` with leading *0* by using `sprintf` but with an **integer** as argument:

```
sprintf(out_str,"%010d",some_integer);  //out_str is a string of 11 characters
```

but now I have only two methods left for padding a **string** (containing numerals) with leading zeros:

**1st Method**

```
char main_string[11] = "12345";
char temp_string[11] = "";

sprintf("temp_string,"%010d", atoi(main_string));

strcpy(main_string,temp_string);
```

**2nd Method**

```
char main_string[11] = "12345";
char temp_string[11] = "";

memset(temp_string,'0',sizeof(temp_string));

strcpy(temp_string + sizeof(temp_string) - 1 - strlen(main_string), main_string);

strcpy(main_string, temp_string);
```

If I try using `sprintf` with `string` as argument I get leading blanks:

```
char main_string[11] = "12345";
char temp_string[11] = "";


sprintf(temp_string,"%010s",main_string);
printf("%s",temp_string);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
     12345   //leading spaces
```

Is there any simple method to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess you'll have to use `strlen` for that. A string cannot guess that you want some 0s before your number, so  you have to explicitely say it or print it another way.

Comment: You could put the second method inside of a function. I don't think there is a way to set the pad character to anything other than space for strings in printf.

Comment: The leading zero in `"%010s"` does NOT apply to the `%s` conversion specifier. See [man 3 sprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) (or enable compiler warnings and it will tell you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you want the padded string in the original array, you can use `memmove` to shift the number to the end of the array, and then use `memset` to fill with zeros.

```
char str[11] = "12345";
size_t text_size = strlen(str) + 1;
memmove(str + sizeof(str) - text_size, str, text_size);
memset(str, '0', sizeof(str) - text_size);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another method would be to simply loop over `temp_string` after your `sprintf` and replace spaces with zeros, e.g.

```
char *p = temp_string;

sprintf (temp_string, "%10s", main_string);

while (*p && *p == ' ')
    *p++ = '0';

puts (temp_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally write function like this

```
char *leadingzeroes(char *buff, char *number, size_t size, int mode)
{
    char *saved;
    size_t len = 0;
    const char *wrk;

    if(!buff) buff = number;
    saved = buff;
    while(*number && (!isdigit(*number) || *number == '0')) number++;

    wrk = number;
    while(*wrk++);
    len = wrk - number - 1;
    if(mode)
    {
        size = size - len;
    }
    memmove(buff + size, number, len + 1);
    while(size--) *buff++ = '0';
    return saved;
}
```